# How to Customize Websphere Error page not to reveal stack trace for a spring application's errors/exceptions

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, server, websphere

How to **`Customize Websphere Error page`** not to reveal stack trace for a spring application's errors/exceptions?

I have configured an error page in `web.xml` for all exceptions.
For a Multi`partFileUpload MAxFileSize error` while uploading 11mb File, where in 10 mb is max file size configured, I get websphere's default error page with error stack trace as mentioned below. How to override this to get the custom error page configured in web.xml?

> SRVEXXXXE: The server cannot use the error page specified for the application.